# SQL Server query: join query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following tables below:

```
Monster:  
Name     Description              EatsPeople 
Vampire  Pale, afraid of light    True 
Ghost    See-through, annoying    False 
Wraith   Green-ish, ugly, dumb    True 

TagLookup: 
Name    ID 
Ghost   1 
Ghost   2 
Wraith  1 

Tags: 
ID    Text                      Value 
1     Green                     green-skin 
2     Screams like a banshee    banshee-call
```

To return any monsters with the 'green-skin' tag applied, I do this:

```
  SELECT m.Name, m.Description, m.EatsPeople 
  FROM dbo.Monster AS m 
  INNER JOIN dbo.TagLookup AS tl 
    ON m.Name = tl.Name 
  INNER JOIN dbo.Tags AS t 
    ON t.ID = tl.ID 
    AND t.Value = 'green-skin';
```

But how would I also return the text field of the Tags table along with the monster info?

Comment: Have you tried adding `t.Text` in the `SELECT` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include it along with the other items, referring to it by `t.Text`:

```
SELECT m.Name, m.Description, m.EatsPeople, t.Text
```

Comment: Without another query, is it possible to return a boolean indicating if the tag say 'pretty pointless' is applied?